# Why is jQuery UI accordion open/close animation so choppy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've been trying to figure this one out and I just can't see any issues - as well, the same accordion (same jqueryui version 1.9.2) works with no issues on another site, I even switched the theme to use the same one as the other site and I still get the choppiness on this one.

And it shouldn't be the jquery ui theme either as it's working fine **[here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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)**

Any ideas what it might be?

Comment: Paste the JavaScript call to the acordion. Are there any optional parameters passed?

Comment: Your HTML markup invalid. You can not have h1 and div elements inside of paragraph tags. Run the code through an html validator and fix the problems.

Comment: @epascarello didn't even notice that - it must have been added by wordpress editor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
}
```

The issue is with this css. If you change it to px instead of em, it functions correctly.

Comment: And the reason this makes a difference is most likely due to the font settings around said accordion, such as the accordion's parent not having the same font-size as the body.

Comment: It's strange but for me it's vice versa. If I change to px padding animation is jerky and if I go back to at least 0.65em it's smooth.

Answer (score 14):

For future readers, I have also experienced this issue when I hadn't wrapped the content of my accordion row in a div tag:

**Bad:**

```
        <div class="accordion">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
            <table class="address">
                <tr><td>...</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

**Good:**

```
        <div class="accordion">
            <h3>Delivery Address</h3>
            <div>
                <table class="address">
                    <tr><td>...</td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I was pretty frustrated before I got this point

Comment: Same here, tried doing without div wrapper and this caused choppiness.. Returned div and all good.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. After looking a few different solutions. I found it was a margin issue.

This worked for me:

```css
#accordion .ui-accordion-header {
    margin:0;
}
```

I have the `hightstyle` set to content by the way.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was caused by the margin of my accordion titles, and the margin of the elements inside my accordion content. You will need to set the margins of those elements to 0.  If you want to add space between those elements you can use padding and it wont cause issues.

```
#accordion h3 {
margin: 0;
padding: 10px 0;
}
#accordion p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

I used paragraphs tags inside the divs of the accordion content. If you use something else, make sure the margin of that element is set to 0.

Comment: FYI - I stripped the accordion down to its bare bones and it was still jumping down during animations and back up when complete.  I then added these styles above, and the problem fixed itself.

Comment: Also, for me, `#accordion h3 { margin: 0; }` was the only style that mattered.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a nested accordion in Drupal which was built using Views Nested Accordion. I removed line 38 of the views-nested-accordion.css which has `.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {height: auto !important;}` and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

The key to the smooth action is the "heightStyle" EG

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Comment: ...and make sure you aren't explicitly setting the height (even to auto) of the content panels. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten to add all file dependencies, in  tag

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.georgiancollege.ca/programs/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.8.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.georgiancollege.ca/programs/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.georgiancollege.ca/programs/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.georgiancollege.ca/programs/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.georgiancollege.ca/programs/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.button.min.js?ver=1.9.2'></script>
```

include all dependencies then it should work fine..